# Minimize distance between matrices subject to row and column margin constraints

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to solve for a matrix possessing predetermined row and column totals that most closely resembles a second predetermined matrix possessing the same properties (but possibly with different row/column totals).

So, both matrices must satisfy the following: 
All elements of must be in the range [0,1].

Any element with a column number less than row number must be 0 in the solution.

Any element with column number greater than row number + 2 must be 0.

So starting with something like this:

```
0.07    0.17    0.47    0.29        

0.07    0.1     0.14    0        0.31
0       0.07    0.18    0.07     0.32
0       0       0.15    0.04     0.19
0       0       0       0.18     0.18
```

I would like to minimize the ‘distance’ to this:

```
0.10    0.21    0.37    0.32        

0.10    0.11    0.12    0        0.33
0       0.10    0.13    0.10     0.33
0       0       0.12    0.09     0.21
0       0       0       0.13     0.13
```

Such that the original row and column totals from the first matrix are preserved. I would be defining the distance here to be the sum of squared differences between the ith, jth entries in each matrix, but if this is an issue for some reason I would be Ok with using some other measure.

So far I have been trying to do this using solnp in the Rsolnp package like this:

```
rowVals<-c(.31,.32,.19,.18)
colVals<-c(.07,.17,.47,.29)
In<-c(.07,.15,.1,.18,.04,.14,.07)
tar<-c(.1,.11,.12,0,0,.1,.13,.1,0,0,.12,.09,0,0,0,.13)
tar<-matrix(tar,byrow=T,nrow=4)


makeMat <- function(x,n) {
  ## first and last element of diag are constrained by row/col sums
  diagVals <- c(colVals[1],x[1:(n-2)],rowVals[n])
  ## set up off-diagonals 2,3,4,5,6
  sup2Vals <- x[(n-1):(2*n-3)]
  sup3Vals <- x[(2*n-2):(3*n-5)]

  ## set up matrix
  m <- diag(diagVals)
  m[row(m)==col(m)-1] <- sup2Vals
  m[row(m)==col(m)-2] <- sup3Vals
  m
}


##objective function
fn<-function(inpt, targt, n, ...){
  x<-makeMat(inpt, n=n)
  y<-targt
  z<-sum((x-y)^2)
  z
}

##equality constraint function
eq<-function(x,...){c(rowSums(makeMat(x,length(rowVals))),colSums(makeMat(x,length(colVals))))}
##row/column constraints
eqB<-c(rowVals, colVals)


opt1<-solnp(pars = In, fun = fn, eqfun = eq, eqB = eqB, LB = rep(0,7), targt = tar, n=4)
```

However, when I try to solve I am getting this error:

```
solnp-->Redundant constraints were found. Poor
solnp-->intermediate results may result.Suggest that you
solnp-->remove redundant constraints and re-OPTIMIZE

Iter: 1 fn: 0.0116   Pars:  0.07000 0.15000 0.10000 0.18000 0.04000 0.14000 0.07000
solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.
```

I have also encountered something like this:

```
Error in solve.default(a %*% t(a), constraint, tol = 2.220446e-16) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0
```

I hope I am explaining this problem clearly enough; any suggestions on how I might approach this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your constraints on the sum of the elements of the rows and columns are redundant (once you know the sum of all the columns, you know the sum of all the elements): try removing one, e.g., the sum of the elements of the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks!

It looks like using something like this for the equality constraint function works:

```
##equality constraint function
eq<-function(x,...){c(rowSums(makeMat(x,length(rowVals)))[-c(4,3)],colSums(makeMat(x,length(colVals)))[-1])}
##row/column constraints
eqB<-c(rowVals[-c(4,3)], colVals[-1])
```